# Spark and lazy loading of static resources

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, lazy-loading

I have a lazily-loaded static java class - it exposes a method `getValue(Key key)`.  On the first call to `getValue`, it loads some data and does some relatively expensive computations.  Subsequent calls are very fast.  I also have (in Scala) an RDD[Key], `rdd`, and would like to do something along the lines of `rdd.map(StaticClass.getKey)`.  My question is: does the serialization of the `StaticClass` closure include the resource data, and therefore mean that that data will be shuffled across the network?  Or will the loading only happen on the executors (which I think is what I want)